# r-value causes a warning without the use of std::move

Tags: c++, c++14, move-semantics, rvalue-reference

Can someone help me to understand why the following code causes a warning

```
struct A
{
  A() : _a( 0 ) {}

  const int& _a;
};


int main()
{
  A a;
}
```

with warning

```
warning: binding reference member '_a' to a temporary value [-Wdangling-field]
      A() : _a( 0 ) {}
```

but this code, where `std::move` is used to initialize the member `_a`, does not:

```
struct A
{
  A() : _a( std::move(0) ) {}

  const int& _a;
};


int main()
{
  A a;
}
```

Aren't `0` and `std::move( 0 )` both r-values?

Comment: Where does _a refer here ?

Comment: `_a` is a reference, in ex1 you bind it to a temporary (`0`), using it later is UB. In ex2 you use `std::move` as a cast to "lie" to the compiler, it silences the warning but accessing it later is still UB.

Comment: `const &` does not extend the lifetime when used in a class.  It only works for function parameters and function returns.

Comment: @NathanOliver I think you're mixing it up with something else. `foo(bar{});` won't change the lifetime of the `bar` from spanning the full-expression, on the other hand `bar const &b = bar{};` does extend the `bar`'s lifetime without a function in sight.

Comment: @Quentin Yeah there is a couple other cases.  My main point was that you cannot pass a temporary to a class by `const &` and have the class extend the lifetime.

Comment: @NathanOliver indeed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is an expression:

```
0
```

It's a very small expression, true. But it is an expression.

Once the expression is evaluated, it goes away. It disappears. Joins the choir invisible. Goes to meet its maker. It becomes an ex-expression.

It is true that binding a `const` reference to a temporary extends the scope of the temporary value until the end of the enclosing scope.

But in this case, the scope of the expression is the constructor. When the constructor is done, the temporary value gets destroyed.

Your compiler noticed the fact that a `const` reference to the expression still continues to exist, though, as a class member. Your compiler is advising you that using the class member will now result in undefined behavior. Your compiler wants to be your friend. Your compiler doesn't want you to write buggy code, so you're getting some free, friendly advice, from your compiler.

In the other case, you have added some additional code which is slightly more complicated. It is still undefined behavior, but the code is now complex enough that the compiler cannot see that undefined behavior results. But it's still the same bug.

A compiler will try to warn you of potential problems, when the compiler sees them. Unfortunately, the compiler cannot find all possible potential problems, every time. But, when it's obvious, the compiler will let you know.

Comment: Absolute prose.

Comment: are you sure about this? If that was the case, one won't be able to have smart pointers ever.

Answer (score -1):

Their return values are not exactly the same.
From [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move)

> In particular, std::move produces an **xvalue** expression that identifies
>   its argument t. It is exactly equivalent to a static_cast to an **rvalue**
>   **reference** type.

Now, looking at rvalue references, we see that object "0" in second example can live longer:

> An rvalue may be used to initialize an rvalue reference, **in which case
>   the lifetime of the object identified by the rvalue is extended until
>   the scope of the reference ends.**

Such reference (rvalue reference) is afterwards assigned to the class member _a, which is allowed, so you are having no error.

Moreover, rvalue reference to a temporary can be used in a move constructor, so if the member you are initialising has it, I don't see the problem. However, in C++ you can never know when undefined behaviour can suddenly hit you :)

Comment: Cppreference explains this where it explains lifetime extension. Now linked from the sentence you quoted.

Comment: @Cubby, sorry, what is linked now? Shall I link something?

Comment: The word "extended" in that sentence on cppreference is now clickable, and leads to the page that explains the problem.