# Does the following code has undefined behavior due to r-value usage

Tags: c++, class, rvalue-reference

According to the post 
[r-value causes a warning without the use of std::move](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40678256/r-value-causes-a-warning-without-the-use-of-stdmove),
I'm wondering if the following code has undefined behavior:

```
struct Animal
{
  virtual void foo() const
  {
    std::cout << "error" << std::endl;
  }
};

struct Dog : public Animal
{
  void foo() const
  {
    std::cout << "wuff" << std::endl;
  }
};

struct A
{
  A( const Animal& a) : _a( a ) {}

  void foo()
  {
    _a.foo();
  }


  const Animal& _a;
};

int main()
{
  A a( Dog{} );
  a.foo();

}
```

On my machine, the output is (as expected) `wuff`.

Answer (score 4):

Indeed, `a.a_` is a dangling reference in the statement `a.foo();`, and so the evaluation of the expression `_a.foo` has undefined behaviour. The lifetime of the temporary object `Dog{}` ends at the end of the full-expression (and is *not* extended).

Comment: Do you know any fix or workaround?

Comment: @abraham_hilbert: Take the value by const pointer: `A(const Animal* p) : a_(*p) {}`. That makes it *much* harder to accidentally pass the address of prvalue in.